# Can you run a .class file from terminal that is outputted by an IDE

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to run a file from command line.  The file is a .class file and is apart of a larger project that I compiled in Netbeans.  I navigated to the .class file and ran

java MyFile

And I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PersonTest/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PersonTest.class
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205) 
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321) 
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294) 
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)

Could not find the main class: PersonTest.class. Program will exit
```

Whats up with that?  (I should mention that i'm running ubuntu)

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError - and what else?  did it complain about MyFile or another 'subservient' class?

Comment: heres the full error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PersonTest/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PersonTest.class
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: PersonTest.class. Program will exit

Comment: did you set up your classpath?

Comment: Bobby, I have posted the answer to your problem - please see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check this useful link [java - the Java application launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):

> By default, the first non-option
>   argument is the name of the class to
>   be invoked. **A fully-qualified class
>   name should be used**

So, you have to write the full qualified name of the class (this includes the package name).

So, the right way to execute your command is this (from the root dir where your class files are stored):

```
> java my.package.MyFile
```

Also, make sure to include all the needed dependencies at the classpath (-cp) argument (check the referenced link).

**UPDATE:** to include a classpath setting example:

```
java -classpath C:\MyProject\classes;C:\MyProject\lib\utility.jar my.package.MyFile
```

With this, the java runtime will search for the classes at the C:\MyProject\classes directory, and at the C:\MyProject\lib\utility.jar JAR file. You'll need not only your class direct dependencies, but the dependencies needed by the referenced files (the whole tree).

Comment: Have you run it from the root classes dir? And set the dependencies at the classpath?

Comment: so, if this file imports 4 other files then i need to pass paths to these 4 files?

Comment: No. You have to tell the java command where to search those dependencies. See my update.

Comment: Too bad he accepted an answer that will not solve his problem. Yes, there is a lot of important information, but it doesn't contain the solutions. See his stack trace and see my answer to see why.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: The stack trace was not available when I wrote my answer, and still, giving him just some useful information has helped him to solve his problem. "Show me to fish instead giving me fishes"

Comment: @Tomas - 100% agreed, my comment is aimed at the OP.  Fishing rather than fishes is the best way and kudos for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be in this line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PersonTest/class
```

It means you didn't type:

```
java MyFile
```

as you said in your original post, you typed

```
java PersonTest.class
```

you should have typed

```
java PersonTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, they are compiled by a java compiler. If you have the right version of the jvm (often other versions work aswell) than it can be run. The information about your error is not enough to tell what went wrong.
Your probably in the wrong folder, mistyped the classname, used a class in your code that couldn't be found, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your class is entirely standalone (i.e. only references `java.lang` classes like `String`), you'll need to add other classes/JARs to the classpath when you invoke Java.

The `NoClassDefFoundError` (which usually states the name of the class by the way, and always includes a stacktrace) indicates that an external class that was available when your class was compiled, is not available on the classpath at runtime.

**EDIT** based on update:

You're invoking your process incorrectly.  You don't need to append the `.class` suffix of the file - doing so makes Java look for a file class `class` in a subpackage.

(P.S. you said you ran `java MyFile`.  That's a lie, you actually ran `java PersonTest.class`.  If you'd noted that to start with, it would have made it much easier for people to answer the question!)

Answer (score 0):

Just consider this example

say I already have a folder src and I wrote in my notepad

```
package test.oye;

class testclass {
static public void main (String [] args)
{
int a=3;
System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

then what go to src folder and you ,yourself create a folder named test and inside it oye . Then put your .java file in it . Then `cd src/test/oye` only(in Command prompt or terminal).From there itself

```
javac testclass.java
cd src
java test.oye.testclass
```

This will work for sure.

If you don’t want to put .java file there … then just compile your .java file and get the .class file .
Now create the test folder and then oye inside it ….and put .class file inside it ….

Now go back to src …and then type

```
java test.oye.testclass;
```

Answer (score 0):

according to terminal ide, android requires classes in DEX format when running them.

Try:

> dx --dex --output=practice.jar practice.class

Then run using this:

> java -jar practice.jar practice